# How to redirect to a page as an action

Tags: java, redirect, actionlistener

I hava a Menu like this:

```
JMenu forum = new JMenu("Forum");
forum.addMenuListener( new MenuListener(){
    public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {

    }
    public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {

    }
    public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {

    }
});
menubar.add(forum);
```

and as menuSelected action, I want to redirect to a page, for example, page.html
How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a link in browser with java button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967451/open-a-link-in-browser-with-java-button)

Comment: It is not a desktop application but it is a JApplet Menu, how can i do this in that case?

Comment: Be sure to mention that in your question next time, as that requires a completely difference approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Desktop myDesktop=Desktop.getDesktop() 

public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
       myDesktop.browse(uri);
    }
```

for Applet use below code(I get the code from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/applet_newwindow.htm))

```
String link = "http://www."+source.getLabel()+".com";
      try {
         AppletContext a = getAppletContext();
         URL url = new URL(link);
         a.showDocument(url,"_blank");
      }
```

Comment: It is not a desktop application but it is a JApplet Menu, how can i do this in that case? Additionally, i want the current url to open the redirect url in the same tab

Comment: that didnt work either. I wrote the code below as you suggested but nothing shows up when I click Forum. The output shows "Forum Clicked" and does not show exception error message but no redirection too
System.out.println("Forum clicked");
            panel.removeAll();
            String link = "http://www.google.com";
            try {
                AppletContext a = getAppletContext();
                URL url = new URL(link);
                a.showDocument(url,"_blank");
            }
            catch (Exception err) {
                System.out.println("Not opening url");
            }

Comment: It works now but do not open it in the same tab, but opens it like a pop-up