# How to trigger links on Java application without use JButton

Tags: java, browser, hyperlink, triggers, default

In my java application, I have a list of links which I would like to open in default browser:

[image: Link List]

How to open it is pretty much clear based on this answer [Open a link in browser with java button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967451/open-a-link-in-browser-with-java-button).

What I'm trying to find out now is, how do I know which one of the links I'm triggering since they are all together in a file.

Does anyone has a good suggestion to this? because until now the only thing I could thought was create a JButton to each link and detect it through a listener but this seems not to be the most efficient solution. The links needs to be opened individually and If its possible I would like to trigger directly through the link.

Comment: Do you want to open all of them at once? The question is not very clear...

Comment: sry, I will edit - each one through time, not all at once

Comment: Still unclear. Do you want a button that will open the links one by one, one after another, until the end of the list? Please try to clarify what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the help man, but I found my own answer - maybe now will be more clear to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my own answer. Java provides an interface named [HyperlinkListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/HyperlinkListener.html).  With `HyperlinkListener` you can detect which link is being triggered.

In code lines this means:

```
    @Override
public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent arg0) {

        if(arg0.getEventType().toString() == "ACTIVATED")
            System.out.println(arg0.getURL());  
            //openWebpage(arg0.getURL());

}
```

This simple code will output the link you want to trigger, and to open in the default browser you just need to merge my answer with the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967451/open-a-link-in-browser-with-java-button) post.