# JEditorPane is not detecting <a> tags, puts them into my string instead

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

Here is my problem:

I'm trying to add links to my JEditorPane with these lines of code:

```
gui.textfield.getDocument().insertString(gui.textfield.getDocument().getLength(), guiModel.getResponseString(serverResponse), null);
```

and

```
public String getResponseString(String serverResponse){ 
    return currentDate()+" "+serverResponse.replaceAll("http://.+?(com|net|org|de)/{0,1}", "<a href=\"$0\">$0</a>")+"\n";       
}
```

Note that gui.textfield is my JEditorPane.

However, I can see it's working, but the whole Tag just lands in the string, and is not being detected as a link.

My JEditorPane has these adjustments:

```
    textfield = new JEditorPane ();
    textfield.setEditorKit(JEditorPane.createEditorKitForContentType("text/html"));
    textfield.setEditable(false);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In fact you just insert the string rather than change the HTMLDocument's structure.

The simplest way to add link would be to create artificial Eleemnt and replace its outer html.

```
SimpleAttributeSet a=new SimpleAttributeSet();
a.addAttribute("DUMMY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME","DUMMY_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE");
doc.setCharacterAttributes(start, text.length(), a, false);

Element elem=doc.getCharacterElement(start);
String html="<a href='"+text+"'>"+text+"</a>";
doc.setOuterHTML(elem, html);
```

See working example of the links autocreation here
http://java-sl.com/tip_autocreate_links.html

Answer (score 0):

TRy to use the method setText to set the text in the editor. If you want the link work as a link (open the browser) you need to add a listener. LOok at this answer: [Open a link in browser with java button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967451/open-link-in-browser-with-java-button)
Also, you can simply add the text of the link like if it was normal html. If it is not the answer you want, probably I don't understand the question. because my English is not so good.