# Automatically open a link in browser and login using java

Tags: java, browser, authentication

I'm trying to find a way using a java code, so that I could provide it with url, username and password and the code automatically opens the link in a browser and login without me having to provide credentials again in the browser when the link opens. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass username and password through get parameters such as:

```
mysite.com/login?username=user&password=user
```

Then you can extract this parameters from request and use them for authentication:

```
@RequestMapping("login")
public String login(@RequestParam(required=false) String username, 
@RequestParam(required=false) String password) {
    if(username != null && password != null) { 
       //perform auth
    }
    return "login";
}
```

But better way would be to associate unique token with each user and login them based on that.

//P.S.
For opening browser with specified url you can use:
[Open a link in browser with java button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967451/open-a-link-in-browser-with-java-button)